# Which is a better way to test validations of ActiveRecord using rspec?And why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord, rspec

I'm going to test a model, like this;

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title
  # ...
end
```

I find two main ways to test the validation:

1.Use thoughtbot's shoulda gem https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda

```
describe Post do
  it { should validate_presence_of(:title) }
end
```

2.Test the validations directly, as the way in the book

```
describe Post do
  it "must has title" do
    post = Post.create
    expect(post).not_to be_valid
end
```

So I wonder which is a better way and why. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first test validates that `Post` declared `validates_presence_of :title`, and the second test validates that *when* `Post` declares `validates_presence_of :title`, and an instance has no title, the instance will not be valid.

On the one hand, since there is no need to test the internals of `validates_presence_of`, the more correct test, should be the first one.

On the other hand, it can be claimed that the first test counts on an implementation detail (the usage of a specific feature), while the second one tests *behavior*, so *it* is more correct.

So both use-cases have rationalizations.

I personally prefer the first one.

**Edit**

I've dug a bit inside the `shoulda` implementation, and it actually tests by setting a `nil` value to the instance, and checking if it has correct errors, so actually, it *does* check for behavior. In that case, definitely you should use it.